How to run two cells in parallel in Jupyter Notebook?
I am wondering if it is possible to run two parallel processes in Jupyter Notebook, in two different cells, so that each process can calculate and print its own results under the cell.
So far I have tried making this work by experimenting with the multiprocessing and the concurrent.futures libraries, but these libraries seem to be able to run parallel processes only in the same cell. I have also tried to make Ipyparallel work, with no luck.
The basic idea is to run two parallel processes in Jupyter Notebook in two different cells and to feed the same function into the two processes, but with different input parameters in each process.
Cell 1: runs function(input A)
cell 2: runs function(input B)
And both cells can print independently under the cell while they are running.

This question is similar to: Ipython Notebook: how to run multiple cells?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What's wrong in running cells one by one?
